# Object creation and adding to a list

Tags: c++

Object creation: I want to create an object of class Note, that is a QWidget. How can I do this? I am only able to show the Note `bla` that has been declared as a private member of class Traymenu. This goes by clicking on "new Note" in the context Menu of the trayMenu. I want to create a new note for each click on this and add it to a list of Notes in trayMenu to keep the note alive, but don't have an idea how to define a list of elements of objects of my own class Note.

So my 2 problems are: How to create a new note on runtime and how to keep it alive in a list that belongs to trayMenu.

If i comment out the 2 lines `Note nwNt`and `nwNt.show()` the compiler says that something in qglobals.h is private.

traymenu.h:

```
#ifndef TRAYMENU_H
#define TRAYMENU_H

#include <QSystemTrayIcon>
#include <QIcon>
#include <QPixmap>
#include <QMenu> //in use for context menu

#include "note.h"

class Traymenu : public QSystemTrayIcon
{
public:
    Traymenu();
    ~Traymenu();
    void createMainContextMenu();
    void newNote();

private:
    QSystemTrayIcon mainIcon;
    QMenu mainContextMenu;
    Note bla;

};
#endif // TRAYMENU_H
```

traymenu.cpp:

```
#include "traymenu.h"
#include <QDebug>

Traymenu::Traymenu(){
    mainIcon.setIcon(QIcon(QPixmap("C:\\papersavers.png")));
    mainIcon.setVisible(true);
    mainIcon.show();

    createMainContextMenu();
}

Traymenu::~Traymenu(){
}

void Traymenu::createMainContextMenu(){
    QAction *actionNewNote = mainContextMenu.addAction("Neue Notiz");  

    QObject::connect(actionNewNote,&QAction::triggered,this,&Traymenu::newNote);


    mainIcon.setContextMenu(&mainContextMenu);
}

void Traymenu::newNote(){
    qDebug() << "in newNote()" << endl;
    //Note nwNt;
    //nwNt.show();
    bla.show()
}
```

note.h:

```
#ifndef NOTE_H
#define NOTE_H

#include <QWidget>

namespace Ui{
class Note;
}

class Note : public QWidget
{
public:
    Note(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Note();

private:
    Q_OBJECT
    Ui::Note *ui;
};

#endif // NOTE_H
```

note.cpp:

```
#include "note.h"
#include "ui_note.h"

Note::Note(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Note)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

Note::~Note()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Comment: Well it doesn't seem you even have a list in your class to hold your nodes. Are you attempting to create a linked list?

Comment: Prefer `std::list` to writing your own.  Also prefer some kind of smart pointer to place into the list.

Comment: Ok so a list with pointers. And what about creating a note?

Comment: How can I tell each note, that they have the same traymenu? I want to call something like `Note newNote(this)` from within class `Traymenu` where `this` is the only instance of Traymenu.